# Mongodb query which stores are open at a given time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, time

I have seen this question asked multiple times, but have not seen any clear answers. I would like to write a mongodb query that takes in time and compares it to store hours. Currently I converted all times to minutes, i.e, 9:00 AM = 540. It works perfectly when store hours do not go beyond midnight. Does anyone have a solution.

example store json:

```
{
"name": "store",
"Monday": [
    {
        "to": 960,
        "from": 1080
    },
    {
        "to": 1320,
        "from": 1500
    }
],
"Tuesday": [
    {
        "to": 960,
        "from": 1080
    },
    {
        "to": 1320,
        "from": 1500
    }
],
"Wednesday": [
    {
        "to": 960,
        "from": 1080
    },
    {
        "to": 1320,
        "from": 1500
    }
],
"Thursday": [
    {
        "to": 960,
        "from": 1080
    },
    {
        "to": 1320,
        "from": 1500
    }
],
"Friday": [
    {
        "to": 960,
        "from": 1080
    },
    {
        "to": 1320,
        "from": 1500
    }
],
"Saturday": [
    {
        "to": 960,
        "from": 1080
    },
    {
        "to": 1320,
        "from": 1500
    }
],
"Sunday": [
    {
        "to": 960,
        "from": 1080
    },
    {
        "to": 1320,
        "from": 1500
    }
],
"position": {
    "lat": 34.14505,
    "lng": -118.36954
},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        -118.36954,
        34.14505
    ]
},
"__v": 0
}
```

current query:

```
router.get('/:second', async (req, res) => {
....
let time = timeConvertor(req.params.second);
let startdate = getDay() + '.0.to';
let endate = getDay() + '.0.from';
let secondStart = getDay() + '.1.to';
let secondEnd = getDay() + '.1.from';
let query = {
   {
   $or: [{
    $and: [ { [secondStart] : { $lte : time }, }, {  [secondEnd] : { $gte : time } } ]},
        {
    $and: [ { [startdate] : { $lte : time }, }, {  [endate] : { $gte : time } } ]}
    ]
};
res.send(await resturants.find(query).toArray());
});
```

Comment: Is that `1500` meant to be next day 1 am ? If that's the case why is that taken as `1500` rather than `60` ?

Comment: @srinivasy the query wouldn't work when I did it with 60 instead. so I made 1500 since the store closes at 1:00 AM. It works when the current time is before midnight but not after.